# Rewriting rules in htaccess to add hyphens between names

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am not sure if this is even possible, but am trying to rewrite some urls in my htaccess file using one line of code rather than to add a separate rewrite for each of my hundreds of urls.

The existing urls are like the one below where the car make and model is in one string.

```
www.exampledomain.co.uk/cars/astonmartindb9/
```

I want to separate the make and model by adding a hyphen as below

```
www.exampledomain.co.uk/cars/astonmartin-db9/
```

Comment: You will have to update your URLs. There is no way for the server to know where the make and model starts and ends to know where to put a hyphen. Maybe give a better example and your current code to if that is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. that's what I'm trying to do, I want to change my existing urls to add the hyphens, and do a 301 redirect so I don't lose my existing rankings in search engines.  I presume I will have to write a separate rewrite for each of the hundreds of urls.

Comment: If there is no common pattern then yes that would be the case.

Comment: Perhaps there is a common pattern of the different makes? Could you list all the makes? That would be less work. Then a redirect could add a dash after the make. I added an answer using that approach.

Comment: Did my answer work for you Mark? Please accept it if it did using the tick at the top left of it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars/(astonmartin|ford|renault)([^/-]+)/$ /cars/$1-$2/ [R=301,L]
```

You need to list all the different makes, separated by pipe characters, as shown. Should be the simplest solution.